# ibatis isNotEmpty with multiple variables

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

Suppose I have a massive table called inactiveUsers and a search form. I want to conditionally join the inactiveUsers table if any user related characteristic is chosen (address, name, phoneNumber, etc...). Is there any way to do this without the following:

```
<isNotEmpty property="address">JOIN inactiveUsers</isNotEmpty>
<isNotEmpty property="phoneNumber">JOIN inactiveUsers</isNotEmpty>
<isNotEmpty property="name">JOIN inactiveUsers</isNotEmpty>
```

and so on for another 10-20 isNotEmpty clauses. I would like to do something like:

```
<isAnyNotEmpty properties="address, phoneNumber, name, ....">JOIN inactiveUsers</isNotEmpty>
```

Is this possible with ibatis? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a boolean property useJoin

```
public boolean isUseJoin() {
        if(!adress.equals("") && !phoneNumber.equals("")&&!name.equals("")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

not perfect but seems better than multiple statements in IBATIS clause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not possible (simply) with iBatis2 . iBatis3 has a `<if>` tag, but nevertheless the syntax would not be very simple.

I'd rather code a pseudoproperty in the object (if you can touch it) to ask for this condition, that would be much simpler.